# Como contar funcionários menores de idade?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

Utilizo o código abaixo para exibir o número de funcionários ativos:

```
{{ $relatorio->Empresa->Funcionario->where('id_status', 1)->count() }}
```

Como faço para contar somente os funcionários que tenham menos de 18 anos?

na tabela de funcionários tenho a data de nascimento no formato `date` "2000-09-23"

Answer (score 0):

A maioria dos bancos de dados, a cláusulas where aceita mais de um parametro. Cassi tenha sido você quem fez esta classe de select, certifique-se de que ela  aceite mais parâmetros.  Esse segundo paramatro seria:
`SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id_status = 1 and colunaDataNascimento::date < '".dates("Y-m-d",strtotime ("-18 years"))."' -- deve estar em ISO-8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD`